# Searching for a set of phrases in a text (JavaScript, RoR)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby

I need to use the information stored on the database to perform a research on a text. What I am trying to achieve is:

1. Returning one of my database columns as an array.
2. Using this data to perform a query on a text.
3. If an item of the array corresponds to a portion of text, this one will be underlined.

Should I use a regex, and, if so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might find useful something like select2 https://teamtreehouse.com/library/using-select2-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more generic one. Probably using a library will be more appropriate here.
E.g http://fusejs.io/